# using IPC mechanism via AIDL file inside an android library

Tags: java, android, ipc, android-library

can i use IPC mechanism via an AIDL file inside an android library project? in fact i want to use an android library jar file in my android application and i want that library connects to another application via an AIDL file. it's possible or i can use AIDL files just in regular android projects? right now in my android library when i want to import AIDL in my code, eclipse doesn't resolve it but in regular android application does it!

what's the problem?